# Do NIC ports get separate network interfaces?

Tags: networking, network-programming, nic

I'm trying to set up multiple static ips on a server. Can this be done with a multi port NIC? What is the purpose of having a multi port NIC? (I know virtualization is an option, I'm just curious about NIC ports)

Comment: A network interface *is* an NIC. Do you mean 'IP Address'?

Comment: Yes I mean ip address

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be done with a multi port NIC?

Yes. You can assign a different ip address to each NIC. Although [you can also do that with a single NIC](https://serverfault.com/questions/223601/multiple-mac-addresses-on-one-physical-network-interface-linux) too.

> What is the purpose of having a multi port NIC?

Same as having multiple NICs, just on a single card. You can connect to multiple networks, or have multiple connections to the same network.

Comment: "Yes. You can assign a different ip address to each NIC" - I don't have separate NIC's. I have just one with four ports. How can I assign multiple IP addresses? Doesn't it just have a single MAC address?

Comment: I don't know what kind of multi-port NIC you have, but the ones I came across are multiple NICs on one card. Every port with its own MAC address.